# How do I get my code to work?The loop somehow terminates when it shouldn't do so

Tags: c, cs50

I have recently started cs50 and I was working on problem set 1 and there is something wrong with my code and I can't figure out what is wrong.The question is to prompt a number between 1 and 8(inclusive). If you don't input a number between 1 and 8(inclusive)it should prompt again.

```
$ ./mario
Height: -1
Height: 0
Height: 42
Height: 50
Height: 4
```

I have tried using a do while loop but if I enter wrong number or right number the loop terminates.

```
int main(void) {

    int n;
    do {

        printf("Height: ");
        n = scanf("%d", &n);

    }while(n < 1 || n > 8);
}
```

It should work like following.

```
$ ./mario
Height: -1
Height: 0
Height: 42
Height: 50
Height: 4
Stored: 4
```

But here is the message it gives when I run it in CLion.

> ```
> C:\Users\acer\CLionProjects\untitled5\cmake-build-debug\hello.exe
> Height:11
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Comment: I think you need to learn what [`scanf` returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: `n = scanf("%d", &n);` ?? Um... whatever you read into `n`, consider it gone with that subsequent assignment.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of scanned results, in your case, `1`. just remove the `n =` or better yet, check for invalid input via `if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { print("error\n"); continue; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assign the return of scan to a variable.

If you want to scan the variable 'n' from the client, just:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

instead of

```
n = scanf("%d", &n);
```

Follows this link can help you understand more
https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c7.htm

Comment: just:

`scanf("%d", &n);`?  Do not ignore the return value.  What happens if the user enters "Z"?  By ignoring the return value, that will never  be detected.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, but also, one should _always_ check the return value. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fscanf.html (specifically, whether it matches the input you gave it.)